# Read Array of Unsigned Long from the hardware serial?

Tags: arduino, esp32

I got an array of unsigned longs

```
unsigned long readings[ 64 ];
```

which I would like to fill from the hardware Serial interface.
Anyway there is no function to read directly unsigned long from it.

- How to fill the array from the serial ?

Comment: Are you receiving the data directly in binary Form or as text representing numbers? In the former case all you need is `Serial.readBytes((byte*) &readings, sizeof(readings));`, in the latter you need a loop of `int i = 0; while (i < 64) readings[i++] = (unsigned long) Serial.parseInt();` although I'm not entirely sure if `parseInt` can read unsigned numbers of maximum size (temporarily returning their signed representations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get something over serial its ASCII characters so you convert chunks of chars to what ever format you need:

```
 unsigned long my_long = 0;
 char inputChunk[] ="2273543"; // you fill that from serial
 my_long = strtoul(inputChunk, NULL, 10);
 Serial.print(my_long);
readings[0] = my_long;
```

As you gave no example how the data comes over serial or how to differentiate between different junks (is it '\n' or some other terminator) thats just a basic howto for ASCII.
As you experiment with '\n' and ASCII here an example:

```
 unsigned long my_long = 0;
 char inputChunk[16] = {'\0'}; // size big enough you fill that from serial

uint8_t strIndex = 0;
uint8_t longCounter = 0;
while (Serial.available())  {
 char readChar = Serial.read();
 if (readChar == '\n') {
    my_long = strtoul(inputChunk, NULL, 10);
    break;
 }
 else {
    inputChunk[strIndex] = readChar;
    strIndex++;
    inputChunk[strIndex] = '\0]; // Keep the array NULL-terminated
 }
 Serial.print(my_long);
 readings[longCounter] = my_long;
 longCounter++;
 if (longCounter>=64) Serial.print("readings[] is full")
}
```

Comment: still trying to find the best way for sending to be honest.

Comment: Currently experimenting with Serial2.write( myUnsignedLong ); in a loop, followed by Serial2.write( '\n' ); but not sure if this is good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use unions for this, saves you from a lot of nasty casting.

```
union{
   uint8_t asBytes[SERIAL_ARRAY_LEN];
   unsigned long asULongs[SERIAL_ARRAY_LEN/sizeof(unsigned long)];
}data;

//use memcpy, or you could for while through and transfer byte by byte;
memcpy(sizeof(SERIAL_ARRAY_LEN, data.asBytes, serialBuffer);

for (int i = 0; i < SERIAL_ARRAY_LEN/sizeof(unsigned long); i++){
   ESP_LOGD(TAG, "%d", data.asULongs[i]);
}
```

Comment: You are quite welcome. I think unions get a bad wrap b/c people forget that every field in them is just the same memory. Worse, you have to remember that the largest type in the union defines the sizeof the union (my advice keep all members the same size if your use-case permits). However, if you need to access or write data which can be used "as" different byte aligned types they save you from a world of ugly code. Coder life hack?